# Apache 502 bad gateway response when using AWS Application Load Balancer and Centos 7

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services, amazon-alb, laravel

I am new in Linux/centos, I configured a Laravel application in my AWS EC2 Instance (Centos 7),The application was working fine but after that I configured a Application Load Balancer to use path based routing, the application is working and instance health check status is "healthy" but when I hit request to the website (like 500 request in 10sec) It shows "502 Bad Gateway", when I refreshed It works.
I don't know how to solve or debug this problem because I am new to this AWS and Linux.

I will really appreciate your help or guidance or any related issue hint so that I can figure out this problem.